# how to addition or substraction rs10 as per input field values changes with my total amount in php.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```html
<div class="row">
   <label>Nationality</label>
   <select name="mymodalnationality" id="mymodalnationality" class="form-control">
      <option label="select">select</option>
      <option selected="selected" ><?php echo $Nationality; ?></option>
      <option label="Albanian" value="Albanian">Albanian</option>
      <option label="Algerian" value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <label>Rooms</label>
   <select  id="mymodalrooms" name="mymodalrooms" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $noOfCity;?>">
      <option  selected='selected' value='1'><?php echo $noOfCity;?></option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <label>Adult</label>
   <select id="mymodaladult" name="mymodaladult" class="form-control">
      <option   value='1'>1</option>
      <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <label>child</label>
   <select id="mymodalchildren" name="mymodalchildren" class="form-control">
      <option   value='1'>1</option>
      <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <label>age</label>
   <select id="mymodalchildrenage" name="mymodalchildrenage" class="form-control">
      <option   value='1'>1</option>
      <option selected='selected' value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <label>Total Amount</label>
   <input name="totalamount" id="totalamount" value="5000">
</div>
```

How i can make changes in my totalamount rate values (addition with 10rs) by changing some of my input fields as night,rooms,adult,child & child age in php codeigniter.
I just add total amount field for consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `jQuery` for that purpose

```
$("#mymodalrooms").on("change",function(){
    if($("#mymodalrooms").val()==="3"){
        $("#totalamount").val(parseInt($("#totalamount").val())+10);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add jquery to add value in amount. You can use on change event for this.

```
$(document).on('change', '#mymodalnationality, #mymodalrooms, #mymodaladult, #mymodalchildren, #mymodalchildrenage', function(){
      var amount = $('#totalamount').val();
      amount = parseInt(amount) + 10;
      $('#totalamount').val(amount);
   });
```